# jQuery events are triggered twice

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery version 1.4.2.
Somehow, all my jQuery functions are triggered twice without any visible reason (one jQuery library include, one document.ready function etc.).

I can solve the problem by unbind every custom-event before binding function to it (`$(...).unbind('click').bind('click', function(){...})`). This method works well with my own functions, but doesn't with external plug-ins (e.g. prettyPhoto).

What could be the source for the problem and how can I solve it?
Thank you!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Eventually I found what causes the problem: a wrap method! Whenever I use it it cause the document.ready function to fire twice. How could I prevent it from doing this?

Comment: It would help to see your code (jQuery/JS and html), and perhaps a live demo reproducing the problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Comment: Going a bit further than David, it's impossible to meaningfully answer this question without seeing your code.

Comment: I suspect your code resides in an external `js` file that you're sourcing more than once. Check for duplicate `<script>` elements in your markup.

Comment: Eventually I found what cause the problem: a wrap method! Whenever I use it it cause the document.ready function to fire twice. How could I prevent it from doing this?

Comment: @SRachamim: Don't wrap the script tag. You are removing it and adding it to the DOM again which makes the browser evaluate it again.

Comment: @Felix Kling: It is very hard for me to avoid this. Can I prevent the code from running the second time by putting it in some If statment?

Comment: @SRachamim: You could set a global variable and check whether it is set. That might work.